# How to I add up to n errors with equal probability in a bit string in python?

Tags: algorithm

I have an input of let's say 3 random bits (e.g. 010).
To this string I have to add up to 2 errors with equal probability (between all possibilities).
You can see the problem as a xor with string of up to 2 "1"s.

There could then be:

- 0 errors: 000 - 1 case
- 1 error: 100, 010, 001 - 3 cases
- 2 errors: 110, 101, 011 - 3 cases

where the ones are the bit flipped in the result.
Each of the cases would happen with probability 1/(1+3+3) = 1/7

At first I thought about generating all M possible strings, choose one out of M with prob 1/M which would give the correct result.
But since the strings are much longer and the number of errors is actually up to a big n, this is not good for my simulation due to space problems.

What would be the fastest algorithm to apply this transformation to the input?

Answer (score 1):

1. calculate the odds of 0, 1, ..., k errors and determine how many you have.

I believe there's no closed formula for the partial sum of the first few terms of the binomial coefficient, so you'll have to add choose(n,0) + choose(n,1) + ... + choose(n,k) to get the total. Then generate a random float and the number of errors is the largest r s.t. the partial sum of the first r of these binomial coefficients, divided by the denominator, is <= the random float.

Here's some Ruby code for step 1:

```
def get_num_errs(num_elts, max_errs)
  # counts is the number of ways of having 0 through max_errs errs. 
  # The i'th index holds the count of ways of having i errors
  
  counts = [1]
  1.upto(max_errs) do |i|
    counts[i] = (num_elts - i + 1) * counts[i-1] / i
  end
  
  counts_sum = counts.sum
 
  # generate a random float in (0,1), call it r  
  r = rand
  
  running_sum = 0
  0.upto(max_errs) do |num_errs|
    running_sum += counts[num_errs].to_f / counts_sum
    return num_errs if running_sum  >= r
  end
end
```

2. Simulate an array of indices using a hash map, and for the i'th error swap the i'th val with one at rand index >= i. These will be your flipped bits.

I don't know Python, so will give sample code in Ruby (for the second step):

```
def f(num_bits, num_errs)
  # Create an empty hash s.t. the default value for h[i] = i
  h = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = k} 
  
  # Create an int variable. Set bits will represent errors.
  ans = 0
  
  0.upto(num_errs - 1) do |i|
    swap_index = rand(num_bits - i)
    ans ^= (1 << h[swap_index])
    h[swap_index] = h[i]
  end
  
  return ans
end
```